# iOS 7 Localization issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6

I am trying to localize my app. It works perfectly fine on iOS 8. If user's language is Turkish it shows Turkish display name, Turkish story board.If user's language is set to another language than Turkish it shows English which is my base language. Every message, storyboard etc all writen in English. On project/Localization Section I set

```
English- Development Language
Turkish
[x] Use Base Internalization
```

However on iOS 7,default is always Turkish. I tested on real device running iOS 7.1 I also tested on simulator both same results. Funny thing is If I set my language to English restart then set to French and restart language stays as English. However if I set to Turkish restart, set to French and restart language stays as Turkish.

I am really frustrated and can't find the reason. I will really appreciate if you can help me on this.

**Info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Default Name</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
    <true/>

    ....
</plist>
```

**InfoPlist.strings** 
I checked all check boxes next to English,Base and Turkish

**English**

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "English Name";
```

**Base**

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Base Name";
```

**Turkish**

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Turkish Name";
```

**Localizable.strings**
I checked all check boxes next to English,Base and Turkish

**Main.storyboard**
I checked all check boxes next to English,Base and Turkish

Comment: Language is preference order based, if you used Turkish more recently than English then that's what the app will use

Comment: Yes this device used to have Turkish language. I changed settings and I set Language and Region as both French. It is not working. I can't test. Do you say that even if it doesn't work on my test device, will it work on actual device whose settings were French? Any other way for me to test this?

Comment: You said you only localised for English and Turkish so what you describe is it working properly

Comment: On iOS 8 it always defaults back to Base Language(Development Language:English) if the language is not Turkish. On iOS 7, it defaults back to Turkish. However I think your first comment is right. I tried on fresh simulator, I set it to French and restarted and installed the App and it indeed showed everything as English. It is very confusing though.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in CFPreferences on iOS 8.x Simulator runtimes.  It is mentioned in the release notes and discussed in other posts on SO.  It's fixed in the iOS 9 Simulator runtime.